# creating variables in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Simple PL/SQL question from a beginner: What is the proper PL/SQL syntax for creating a new variable in an existing dataset?

I'd like to extract the year from a date field (svcdat) in an insurance claims dataset (rpt_claim). The date field is numerical and follows the format YYYYMMDD, for example 20120704 for July 4, 2012.

My first pass at creating a "year" variable was unsuccessful:

```
declare
  year number(4);
begin
  select svcdat into year 
  from rpt_claim
  where year=floor(svcdat/10000);
end;
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract year from a date you probably will use [extract](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions059.htm#i1017161) function, but before that, as you store your dates as numbers, you have to convert them to date datatype using [to_date](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions203.htm#i1003589) function. Here is an example(oracle 11g is used):

```
-- For the sake of simplicity this table contains only one column.
SQL> create table rpt_claim(
  2    date_col number(8)
  3  )
  4  /

Table created

SQL> insert into rpt_claim(date_col) values(20120704);

1 row inserted

SQL> commit;

Commit complete

 SQL> declare
  2    l_year number(4);
  3  begin
  4    select extract(year from to_date(date_col, 'yyyymmdd'))
  5      into l_year
  6      from rpt_claim
  7    where rownum = 1;
  8    dbms_output.put_line(to_char(l_year));
  9  exception
 10    when no_data_found
 11    then dbms_output.put_line('No data has been selected');
 12  end;
 13  /

2012                  --<-- result

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Note, in the example above the query returns 1 (first selected) row, because it was specifically asked (`where rownum = 1`) to do that. In your case will probably more than one record be returned by the query and to handle that you have to use [cursors](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS00602) and [cursor FOR loop](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1155)(for example) to process returned data or [collections](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#CIHIEBJC).

Here is an example of using collections:

```
-- add more records 
SQL> insert into rpt_claim(date_col) 
  2    select 20120704 + level 
  3      from dual 
  4    connect by level < = 5;

5 rows inserted


SQL> commit;

Commit complete

SQL> select * from rpt_claim;

 DATE_COL
---------
 20120704
 20120705
 20120706
 20120707
 20120708
 20120709

 6 rows selected

SQL> declare
  2    type t_years is table of number(4);
  3    l_year t_years;
  4  begin
  5    select extract(year from to_date(date_col, 'yyyymmdd'))
  6      bulk collect into l_year
  7      from rpt_claim;
  8  
  9    if l_year is not empty
 10    then
 11      for i in l_year.first..l_year.last
 12      loop
 13        dbms_output.put_line(to_char(l_year(i)));
 14      end loop;
 15    else
 16      dbms_output.put_line('No data has been selected');
 17    end if;
 18  end;
 19  /

2012
2012
2012          --<-- our result
2012
2012
2012

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```